# How can I set an ActionOverride with metadata API? (Using JSforce)

Tags: metadata-api, button-overrides, action

I am trying to use JSforce to set (update) the type, content, and comment fields on Account's New and Edit actionOverrides. I've been reading the documentation for the SalesForce Metadata API as well as the docs for JSforce, but I'm still not sure how to do this.

How can I get this to work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up figuring this out. I used jsforce.Connection.metadata.read() to get a copy of the current Account metadata, altered the New and Edit actionOverrides, then submitted the altered copy using jsforce.Connection.metadata.update().

Comment: This was helpful. However did you have to update the entire object metadata or could you update just the ActionOverride? Also is read() returning the correct set of actionOverrides for you? I always see "Default" as type even if the action is overridden.

Comment: I just updated the overrides. I made a new metadata object with just the fullName and actionOverrides attributes set, and called update(), passing in the new metadata. This leaves the other attributes alone.

The read() function always said "Default" when I tested in the same org in which I developed this package, but it worked properly when testing in a separate org. It's possible that when you have a managed package, it makes a separate set of metadata for the dev org and the managed package, and it reads the wrong one. Try testing in another org.

Comment: If I deploy my code into an org without a namespace I get the correct actionOverrides. But if I deploy it into a managed org (with namespace) I get "Default" again. Have you found a solution to this?

Comment: Unfortunately not. It's rather frustrating.

Comment: I just played around with the Tooling API and looks like it gives the proper values!